# Define environment with two sections and verbatim

Tags: environments, verbatim

I'am writing a class for the standardization of some documents and I want the interface to be smoothly as possible. One of the things I need is define an environment that produces something like this.

[image]

The titles are fixed and the user must provide the the text below that is split in two and displayed verbatim. I want the interface to be as simple as possible so, I'm thinking of something like this.

```
\begin{myenvironment}
1 2 3
4 5 6
&
1 2 3
1 4 5
\end{myenvironment}
```

I'm having trouble with the verbatim part.

Currently I have defined an environment that is used like this

```
\begin{myenvironment}
\begin{myenvironment1}
1 2 3
4 5 6
\end{myenvironment1}
\begin{myenvironment2}
1 2 3
1 5 6
\end{nyenvironment2}
\end {myenvironment}
```

But is too uncomfortable and hard to read for my needs.

Is there a way to achieve this or something similar?

Comment: Do you need `verbatim` for the contents? If not, `\ttfamily` also provides a typewriter style font without the hassle that allows for arbitrary catcode-content.

Comment: The text must preserve the spaces and newlines. I don't know iff there is a way to do this without verbatim.

Comment: I think the issue Werner was asking was whether the content is pure text (numbers and letters), or does it include special TeX characters such as `#&\$` etc.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I need only numbers and letters.